# AngularJS : Angular copy append $compile does not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, append

Here's my angularjs Controller

```
var $tr = angular.element("#parent" + obj.field_id).find("tbody"),

$nlast = $tr.find("tr:last"),

$clone = angular.copy($nlast);

$clone.find(':text').val('');

var elem = angular.element($clone);

$tr.after($compile(elem)($scope));
```

When I tried to remove $compile it's working but angularjs does not working at all like validation of fields that's why I need to add a $compile but it doesn't seem working to me , please help me I'm new in angularJS

Comment: Probably because you are mixing Angular and jQuery together (from your tags)? Also may I ask why you are currently learning a library that's been deprecated for almost 5 years (Angular 2 came out in September 2016)? Also I'm not sure why you are trying to select and clone DOM elements with Angular. That's absolutely not how the framework works. Like, `.find(':text').val('')` this has absolutely nothing to do in an AngularJS/Angular/React/Vue app

Comment: This is company requirement to learn AngularJS, I don't know if this  correct approach to append a last row in table using angularJS

Comment: Joshua, no it isn't. In angular your table would be built from an array or object and to add another TR you would push() to your array

Comment: I know this isn't what you were after, but I gave a basic demo of a table built in angularJS and how to add a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a simple table built from an object in angularJS. It's not the only way, but it illustrates some basic concepts, and how to add another row.

In the controller

```
$scope.tabledata = {
  header: [{name: "id"}, {name: "name"}, {name: "email"}],
  rows: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Joe",
      email: "joe@1.com"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Bill",
      email: "bill@1.com"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Sally",
      email: "sally@1.com"
    }
  ]
}

// later I want to add another row:

$scope.tabledata.rows.push({
  id: 4,
  name: "Bob",
  email: "bob@1.com"
})

// and like magic, another row is added to the table
```

The view file:

```
<table ng-if="tabledata">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="item in tabledata.header">{{item.name}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in tabledata.rows">
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow! this help's me a lot by the way thank you, I only have one issue

Comment: look at my sample. there's an ng-repeat for tr and another for td. you only have it on the td

Comment: I got the same issue even I tried to add in tr ng-pattern  I already follow your pattern, Is it possible to append a TR tag close in table  when I push new array ?

Comment: I see  `<tr><td ng-repeat="gridData in form....` in your code, I don' t see a ng-repeat on the `tr`

Comment: The append happens through the object (array). It doesn't happen through DOM manipulation'

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual code

```
         <table class="table table-bordered"  border="" cellpadding="" cellspacing="" style="background-color:white" id="parent{{form.field_id}}">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr >
                                   <th ng-repeat="Col in form.GridList">{{Col.field_title}}</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                     <tr >   
                                     <td ng-repeat="gridData in form.GridList">
                    
                                    <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'Textbox' && gridData.field_datatype == 'Text'">
                                      <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'True'">
                                       <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                                          <div class="Textbox">
                                           <div ng-if="gridData.enable_textformat == 'True'">
                                           <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"   ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="{{gridData.field_textformat}}" type="text" ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == true"   class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                            <div ng-else>
                                           <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"    ng-model="gridData.value"  type="text"  placeholder=""  ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == true"  class="{{gridData.field_required}} col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'False'">                               
                                          <div class="control-group">
                                          <div class="Textbox">
                                             <div ng-if="gridData.enable_textformat == 'True'">
                                                <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="{{gridData.field_textformat}}" type="text"  ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == false" class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                             </div>
                                               <div ng-else>
                                             <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"      ng-model="gridData.value"  type="text"  placeholder="" ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == false" class="{{gridData.field_required}} col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                          </td>       
                                   </tr>
                                 
                                  
                                   </tbody>
                                </table>
```

and This is my angularjs controller
function createDataTable(field) {

```
                    field.GridList = [{}];

                    var appendValue = "";
                    $scope.isread = "";
                    var row = 1;
                    var col = "";
                    try {


                        $http({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: "DefaultForm.aspx/populaGridView",
                            data: "{'fieldid':" + field.field_id + "}",
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
                        }).then(function onSuccess(response) {


                            field.GridList = JSON.parse(response.data.d);



                            $scope.Tables = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
                            angular.forEach(field.GridList, function (vals, keys) {


                             
                                
                                if (vals.field_type == "dropdownList") {
                                    $http({
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        url: "DefaultForm.aspx/populaDD",
                                        data: "{'fieldid':" + vals.field_id + "}",
                                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
                                    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {

                                        try {
                                            vals.Newvalue = [];
                                            vals.Newvalue = JSON.parse(response.data.d);


                                        } catch (err) {
                                        }


                                    }, function myError(response) {

                                    });

                                }
                            })


                        }, function myError(response) {
                            alert(response.statusText);

                        });

                    } catch (err) { console.log("new error " + err.message); }


                };
```

button add new row to the table

```
    $scope.AddRow = function (obj) {

                    var row = { cells: [] },
                    se = obj.GridList,
                     rowLen = se.length; 
                    angular.forEach(se, function (vals) {
                    row.cells.push({ field_type: vals.field_type });
                    })
                    se.push(row);
              
                }
```

when button is clicked it goes to the 1st row not in 2nd row.
[image: button clicked]